# How do I display the parameter value in animate, similar to how it's done in manipulate?

Tags: animation

When I use manipulate, there is a 'plus sign' in the top right that, if I click on, shows my parameter value.  I used animate, because other posts suggested that it solved other issues I had, but now there is no 'plus sign'.  I'm sure I could add the value as text in the plot, but is there some OPTION that I can just set to include the 'plus sign'?

Here's my code, not that I think that it's useful for understanding my question:

```
f[x_] := x^2
a = 2;
Animate[Plot[{f[x], (f[a + h] - f[a])/h (x - a) + f[a]}, {x, -1, 9}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {-1, 11}}], {{h, 2}, 0.000001, 2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Comment: Hi! Why not post a *minimal* working example (preferably without fancy typesetting to make it easy to parse)?

Comment: @Yves Really I don't think any code example at all is needed.  The question is pretty straightforward without it unless there is a complication.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard agreed. But I would prefer a MWE for asthetical reasons over the present code. But then your answer takes care of that.

Comment: @Yves, thank you for the suggestion.  I've attached a minimal example.

Comment: Appearance -> "Labeled" gives me the error message, "An improper nine patch image input option was encountered."  When I remove that segment of code, it works properly.

Comment: @Joe I'm guessing you're using *Mathematica* version 8, or at least not the newest version. In version 8, I can confirm that `Appearance -> "Labeled"` doesn't work. Since you accepted the solution, does that mean you're not looking for a workaround anymore?

Comment: @Jens, exactly, I'm on Mathematica 9.0.  No, thank you. I don't want to take up anyone's time just because I'm on an old version.

Comment: Would `ControlType -> Manipulator` work for you? I do have the "plus sign" but it's quite buggy for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pEB92.png

Comment: Thank you all!  I didn't intend for so many people to take time to answer my little question.  This code will work great to help my students understand what a derivative is. Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Manipulate` with two controls, a `Slider` and an `Animator`, both attached to a single dynamic variable:

```
ClearAll[f, h, x];
f[x_] := x^2
a = 2;

Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x], (f[a + h] - f[a])/h (x - a) + f[a]}, {x, -1, 9}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, {-1, 11}}], 
 Row[{Control[{{h, 1, "h"}, 0.001, 2, Slider[##, Appearance -> "Labeled"] &}],
      Control[{{h, 1, ""}, 0.001, 2, 
        Animator[##, AnimationRunning -> False,
               AppearanceElements -> {"StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton",
                  "PlayPauseButton", "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"}] &}]}]]
```

[image]

Note: You can also use just `LabeledSlider` instead of `Slider[##, Appearance -> "Labeled"] &`.

Comment: I confirm that this works in v7.0.1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, does it work in v10? When I tried on Wolfram Cloud I got  the error message "Animator is not currently supported in the Wolfram Cloud".

Comment: Yes it does.  That is apparently a Cloud limitation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard et al., `Animator` runs in the front end.  The front end clocks the animated variable and triggers the updates when the kernel is ready.  That may be the problem.  (Mr. Wizard's example doesn't use the kernel at all when it's running.)

Comment: Thank you!  I don't understand that code, but it works perfectly on my system.

Answer (score 13):

Adding `Appearance -> "Labeled"` to the control specification seems to work:

```
Animate["foo", {u, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

---

The code above was reported not to work in *Mathematica* 9.  Here is an alternative that works in *Mathematica* 7.0.1 and presumably 8 and 9 as well:

```
Animate["foo", {{u, 0, Dynamic[u]}, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

This *replaces* the label `u` with the slider value but in many cases I think that could be acceptable.

Alternatively you could simply put the slider value inside the body of the `Animate`, e.g.:

```
f[x_] := x^2
a = 2;
Animate[Plot[{f[x], (f[a + h] - f[a])/h (x - a) + f[a]}, {x, -1, 9}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {-1, 11}}] ~Labeled~ h, {{h, 2}, 0.000001, 2}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Notably **not** easily found in the documentation.  (One has to guess that `Animator` options can be used.)  +1.

Comment: @MichaelE2, with so many examples of undocumented features brought to light by M.SE users, is there a tag to identify answers such as this (to a specific version of course, eg V10.0.1)?

Comment: Thank you for finding that option for me!  I searched through the documentation, but couldn't find anything that worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for me. I get an error message that says, "An improper nine patch image input option was encountered."

Comment: Strangely, sometimes when I evaluate the input, the error message does not go away, and yet other times it will go away after a second, and I can run the animation, although it still does not display the value of the parameter.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, sorry for not following the @ convention earlier. I'm fairly new to StackExchange.  Even your "foo" code does not display the value of u on my system.  Maybe it's because I'm still on Mathematica 9.0?

Comment: @Joe The author of the post below which comments are made is automatically notified therefore you do not need `@Mr.Wizard` is this case.  Please see my updated answer for two alternatives that work even in version 7.0.1.

Comment: The option `Appearance -> "Labeled"` is new in V10.  See "Show Changes" in the docs for `Animator`.

Comment: Is there a method you use to find such hidden features @Mr.Wizard?

Comment: @ivbc Just guesswork, really, built on a familiarity with *Mathematica* syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, by post-processing the `Manipulate` code generated by `Animate`:

```
labelAnimator = {u_, u1_, u2_, opts___} :>
  {u, u1, u2,
    Labeled[Animator[Dynamic[u], {u1, u2}, opts],
            Pane[Dynamic[u], {50, Automatic}], Right] &};

Animate["foo", {u, 9.12342345, 12, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}, 
   AnimationRunning -> True}] /. labelAnimator
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. You are all very talented at programming in Mathematica. I'm just a user, a math teacher actually.