# Creating a Dynamic Time Index Slider for List Animate Plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, dynamic, slider, real-time

I am trying to create an animation using ListPlot, which has worked, but I want to be able to see how time is changing (i.e. its dynamic value) as the animation runs. Here is my normal List Plot without the time indicator:

```
ListPlot[
Table[Plot[%25, {y, 0, 150}, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}], {t, 0, 35, .25}]]
```

where %25 is just an equation I am plotting, y is my dependent variable, and t is my independent variable (time) and the parameter I am trying to display.

I tried doing this, but I'm sure its riddled with errors it doesn't give the desired result:

```
ListAnimate[plots, {AnimationTimeIndex -> Dynamic[i], DefaultDuration -> 50, Dynamic[i]}]
```

Please let me know if I am not being clear as to what I want or if you need more information from me. Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: Some ideas can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64494/how-do-i-display-the-parameter-value-in-animate-similar-to-how-its-done-in-man) and I used a dynamic `PlotLabel` [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100120/4999).

Comment: Your code baffles me. What does it mean to `ListPlot` a `Table` of `Plot` objects? Do you get any sensible output from your first line?

Comment: Sorry, I should've explained the original code more. I plot a function based on y and t. Then I create a Table of that function, which basically gives the values of the function for various values of t. Then the ListPlot gives a bunch of screenshots of the function's plot at various values of t (see updated picture). Then I ListAnimate all of this to get a nice animation of the function. BUT the issue is I can't find a way to display the parameter t as the animation runs.

Comment: PlotLabel->t will this help?

Comment: @Wjx unfortuantely no, ut doesn't seem Animate has PlotLabel as an option. It simply gave an error. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Dsmith I mean add it when creating your Plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our unanswered rate, I decide to post this as an answer and hope this can solve your problem:

```
ListAnimate[
 Table[Plot[Sin[t y], {y, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, 
   PlotLabel ->Style[t,30,Bold]], {t, .1, 5, .1}]]
```

This will generate a Animated plot while a number shown above the graph indicate time:

[image: result]

Comment: Perfect! This is the solution I was hoping for :)