# How to show a counter/label in ListAnimate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, animation

Assuming we have a long list of graphs to be shown by `ListAnimate`, we want to locate some interesting ones. Then a counter or slider label for that long list is necessary to keep track of which graph we are viewing.

Searching through the documentation, I cannot find any option to achieve this and [this nice post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64497/11125) works only for `Animate`. Is there a way?

Comment: Then use `Animate`?  `Animate[list[[i]], {{i, 1, Dynamic[i]}, 1, Length@list, 1}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Manipulate` as follows instead:

```
list = Range[100];
Manipulate[list[[i]], {i, 1, Length[list], 1}]
```

Click on the "+" on the right of the control bar and you see further controls and an input field including the frame number.